# Capturing multiple lines of terminal output in R

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I'm trying to obtain the output from multiple lines of code by storing it into a text variable. To generate the output, I am running code into eval(parse()). Please note, the parse() has been sanitized of 'bad' commands via a blacklist and that users sending code are trusted.

Below works perfectly for capturing the output of ONE function that sends text to the console:

```
eval(parse(text=
"x=runif(50,0,1);
y=rnorm(50,0,1);
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y);
summary(df);"))
```

> ```
>   x                 y
> ```
>
> Min.   :0.03062   Min.   :-1.86479
>   1st Qu.:0.27582   1st Qu.:-0.45773
>   Median :0.52880   Median : 0.03051
>   Mean   :0.50302   Mean   : 0.01219
>   3rd Qu.:0.68359   3rd Qu.: 0.36462
>   Max.   :0.97232   Max.   : 3.08798

The above format is perfect for display since it lacks any quotations and terminal line markings (i.e. [1] "..." )

However, if I modify the capture slightly by including a second command that outputs text, I will only receive the output from the last command that generates text:

```
eval(parse(text="set.seed(200);x=runif(50,0,1);y=rnorm(50,0,1);df = data.frame(x=x,y=y);summary(df);
summary(x);"))
```

> ```
>   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
> ```
>
> 0.03062 0.27580 0.52880 0.50300 0.68360 0.97230

One of the ways I've implemented the blacklist is by cycling through the output from parse():

```
mm=parse(text="set.seed(200);x=runif(50,0,1);y=rnorm(50,0,1);df = data.frame(x=x,y=y);summary(df);
summary(x);")
```

> expression(set.seed(200), x=runif(50,0,1), y=rnorm(50,0,1), df = data.frame(x=x,y=y), 
>      summary(df), summary(x))

So, my first instinct to capture multiple commands was to use capture.output(). However, because parse() provides an array of expression()'s, the capture.output() only yields the last eval() except, the output is maligned with additional characters:

```
capture.output(eval(parse(text="x=runif(50,0,1);
y=rnorm(50,0,1);
plot(x,y);
summary(df);summary(x)")))
```

> [1] "    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. "
>   [2] "0.006409 0.218700 0.445300 0.441700 0.635500 0.997800 "

I'm at a loss for where to go from here, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `evaluate` package.

```
code = "x=runif(50,0,1);
y=rnorm(50,0,1);
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y);
summary(df);"

replay(evaluate(code))
```

If you want to save the results to a string,

```
s = paste(capture.output(replay(evaluate(code))), collapse="\n")
cat(s)
```

---

You can save the result returned by `evaluate` in a list.

```
code = "x=runif(50,0,1);
y=rnorm(50,0,1);
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y);
summary(df);
summary(x);
"

dont_print_source = function(x){
    if (class(x)!="source"){
        cat(x)
    }
}
L = evaluate(code)
for(i in 1:length(L)) dont_print_source(L[[i]])
```

Comment: Is there anyway to suppress the terminal lines from being sent to the output? I'm mainly interested in the final results appearing.

Comment: I suggest you to take a closer look of `evaluate`. It basically can do all the things that you want.